# TPROXY with libcurl or http:// streams under PHP

Tags: php, http, sockets, stream, libcurl

I have a PHP app that acts as TPROXY between users and some HTTP resources, i.e. setting the socket in transparent mode by binding to users' IP for the outgoing connections:

```
socket_set_option($outgoing_socket, 0 /*SOL_IP*/, 19 /*IP_TRANSPARENT*/, 1);
socket_bind($outgoing_socket, $incoming_ip, $incoming_port);
```

Got tired fighting with invalid request and response headers, etc. HTTP related stuff, so I'm looking for a much more robust solution like libcurl or http:// streams to take care of the protocol communication part, and to focus my attention only on the payload.

The problem? I couldn't find a way to turn TPROXY mode of the underlying socket for both the solutions:

- unfortunately, CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION doesn't seem to be supported
  in the PHP bindings of libcurl
- without setting IP_TRANSPARENT to the socket, http ['socket']['bind'] context wouldn't accept IPs not assigned to the current machine

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

Comment: One thing: PHP has no `socket_setopt` but it does have `socket_set_option`

Comment: @rdlowrey, socket_setopt is the old name of socket_set_option, but it is still there as undocumented alias. In order to avoid any confusion, I've redacted my question according to your suggestion.

Comment: This is probably not that helpful but PHP, as you have discovered, sucks for "advanced" socket manipulation. Really you could do with rewriting this in a language that allows you direct access to the C-API functions, rather than using the incomplete wrappers that PHP provides.

Comment: @DaveRandom, I thought about that, but my team who does the content adaptation (the actual job of this proxy) is experienced in PHP. It's also much faster to develop filters in PHP than C/C++. Making a C/C++ daemon with embedded PHP seems an overkill for me. One more thing - the performance of the current PHP implementation is good enough - it is able to process a gigabit of traffic at wire speed on a regular hardware.

Comment: @NikolaiGorchilov Then realistically you have two options: 1) Stick with the pure-PHP implementation 2) Write your own code for doing this in C/C++ and compile it as a PHP extension. Maybe you could write your own wrapper for libcurl, or (better) take the existing source for the cURL extension and add support for `CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION`. Does this application need to be distributable, or is it written for a specific bit of hardware that you control?